# Video preview saving hangs in itunes

Tags: ios, ios9, app-store-connect, app-preview

I am trying to upload my app video on itunes. I coverted videos using "Preview Video converter". Video uploads with no error but it stuck in saving. If you refresh the page, it shows that video is in preview and it can take 24 hours but it again stucks their for more than a week and shows that you video is still in preview. Do not know, what to do. :([image].

I used vlc, handbreak, imovie and every software available to correct everything but still it hangs in saving and app preview.